# generar link de descarga de archivo en PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo una pagina en donde quiero generar links de descarga con etiquetas  estas etiquetas se generan en un for y quiero que al dar click en la etiqueta se pueda descargar por ejemplo el archivo 1, luego en la siguiente etiqueta generada se pueda descargar el archivo 2 y asi susesivamente yo ya tengo el nombre de los archivos y sus rutas, pero no se como hacer para descargar los archivos[image: En esta imagen se ve que genero el numero del problema y en el link quiero dejar la opcion para descargar el archivo]

En esta imagen se ve que genero el numero del problema y en el link quiero dejar la opcion para descargar el archivo
este es el codigo que utilizo para generar los links pero no funciona por que al entrar en la pagina me abre la ventana para descargar solo el primer ejemplo sin dar click en el link, los archivos los tengo en una carpeta que se llama subidas:

```
for ($i=1; $i <=count($valores) ; $i++) { 
    echo "<h4>problema ".key($valores)."</h4>";
    echo "<p>Intentos realizados ".$valores[$i]."</p>";
    $nombre=''.key($valores).'_'.$_SESSION["usuario"][0]["matricula"].'.c';
    $ruta='subidas/'.key($valores).'_'.$_SESSION["usuario"][0]["matricula"].'.c';
    //header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$nombre); 
    //header ("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
    //header ("Content-Length: ".filesize($nombre)); 
    //readfile($nombre); 
    //echo "<a href='cuenta.php'>descargar ejercicio</a>"; 
    next($valores);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor explica con más claridad qué es lo que quieres y dónde se encuentra cada cosa. Si es posible, da ejemplos de cómo tendría que construirse la URL del archivo de descarga. Gracias.

Comment: espero asi se entienda mejor... muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno, pero no se trataba de quitar el código que estabas usando... :) Entonces ¿el problema es que el enlace que se crea en `Calificar Problema` no funciona? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de ruta de archivo y volver a poner el código? Gracias.

Comment: el codigo ya lo volvi a poner pero no me quedaba bien asi que lo puse como se fuera html... el problema es que no se como  generar ese link que me permita descargar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es generar una URL válida, los `header` no son necesarios. Lo que tienes es que cuidar de construir bien la URL.

Por ejemplo:

`http://www.tudominio.com/subidas/archivo.extension`

Por supuesto, deber poner datos correctos, o tendrás un error 404.

Puedes probar así.

```
for ($i=1; $i <=count($valores) ; $i++) { 
    echo "<h4>problema ".key($valores)."</h4>";
    echo "<p>Intentos realizados ".$valores[$i]."</p>";
    $nombre=''.key($valores).'_'.$_SESSION["usuario"][0]["matricula"].'.c';
    $ruta='http://www.tudominio.org/subidas/'.key($valores).'_'.$_SESSION["usuario"][0]["matricula"].'.c';
    $URL='<a href="'.$ruta.'">'.$nombre.'</a>';
    echo $URL;
}
```

Comment: y los header en que parte irian aqui para poder descargar el archivo?

Comment: @Yept si quieres crear una URL que apunte al archivo, [algo como esto por ejemplo](https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt) los `header` no irían en ninguna parte. Si quieres que. cuando se haga clic en el enlace el archivo se descargue de una vez, entonces puedes poner les `header`, pero una sola vez, fuera del bucle, asegurándote de que no imprimes nada por pantalla antes de los `header`.

Comment: me parecio muy buena idea la primera que dijiste de poner la ruta en el enlace y creo que lo hare de esta manera... solo para no quedarme con la duda si lo quisiera hacer con los header en las partes de filename, filesize y readfile que pondria? si son distintos archivos los que quiero descargar y estaria afuera del for